# VBA Correl Function: Using specific cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 2-part question. I'm attempting to create a macro to use to calculate the correlation between a set column of data and a variable column of data (meaning, I always want H2:H221 for the first column, but want the second column to jump 220 cells down from the last starting point).

The first question is how do I set those starting and ending cells to be H2 and H221 in worksheet HIIK?
This is the code I have so far:

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CORREL(HIIK!R[-23]C[5]:R[196]C[5],Data!R[19777]C[5]:R[19996]C[5])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

I've tried doing the following, but Excel inserts single parens around H2 and H221, which results in a #name? error.

```
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CORREL(HIIK!H2:H221,Data!R[19777]C[5]:R[19996]C[5])"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

My second question is how do I get it to start the next correlation function 220 cells below the one it started from last time, for the second array in the CORREL function?

Thank you!

Comment: Absolute reference: `=CORREL(HIIK!R2C8:R221C8...`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! 1/2 way there... :)

Comment: Alternately, instead of starting 220 from the top, it could start 1 down from the last cell if that would be easier.

Comment: What's the first starting point? Your code uses relative references but gives no indication where the active cell is when you start adding the formulas.